# Google Sheets - How to display all rows and columns of pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I am trying to display all rows and columns including those that do not have any data in them in my pivot table. Reason being that I want to see all my entries and keep the table size constant. However Google sheets hides all rows/columns that are empty. In Excel, I can check "Show items with no data" to display these rows/columns. Is there a way to do this on Google Sheets?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Haver you read [Google sheets pivot table: show items with no data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864917/1330560) on StackOverflow?

Comment: Hi, thank you ! Yes I have, but was having a hard time understanding the query. I was hoping there was an easier way, but i guess not. I will dig into query. Thanks

Comment: You don’t have to do this alone. Why not create some dummy (or real) data that is representative of your scenario and put it in a shared spreadsheet? That will enable volunteers to work with some actual data and hopefully provide you with some guidance and/or assistance.